# Clients not contacting AD to join domain due to SRV record error

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, essentials-2012, windows-server-essentials

I have a new Server 2012 Essentials, which is a standalone Domain Controller. I am trying to join a client to the domain with an error regarding missing SRV record. I have joined one client to the domain already.

Where do I start, and how can I fix this in DNS? Can I just delete the zones and start over? Or is there a process to fix missing SRV records?

Probably a helpful Event:

Event ID 4013 The DNS server is waiting for Active Directory Domain Services (AD DS) to signal that the initial synchronization of the directory has been completed....

Comment: is the w2k12 your only dns server?

Comment: yes sir there is only one server on the network

Comment: while the second adapter is disabled, wait a while and see if that event resolves.

Comment: Well the second adapter has been disabled for a while, but it was enabled at one point during server setup. Would there be somewhere else this binding could be stuck? 
(Wish I knew why I was downvoted, seems like a pretty legit problem)

Comment: what happens when you try nslookup and type in your domain name? and try it with FQDN. try this on both the server and your clients, both the joined and not-yet-joined.

Comment: also the private adapter on the DC should have just one DNS server record to point to: 127.0.0.1

Comment: This is partially why Im so confused. NSLOOKUP fully resolves IP and FQDN even from a non-domain computer. I just get the error on client unable to contact AD DC, due to "this query was for SRV ldap_tcp_dc_msdc**" something to that effect...
...and I only have one active enabled adapter

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to provide more details about what's what's going wrong if you want a proper answer, [but you can manually add an SRV record through the DNS manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg398680.aspx).  Probably not an optimal solution, because this is most likely a symptom of another problem, but that's how you add SRV records.

You should probably troubleshoot DNS on the client that's having the problem first, as the more likely source of the problem is the client not being able to reach the correct DNS server, than your DNS server(s) actually missing LDAP SRV records.

Comment: Client DNS is not an issue, fresh Win7 install. DNS shows pointing to server. Again, there's only one server. NSLOOKUP resolves to server with FQDN. Can ping server both IP and FQDN.
I can see the ability to create the records, but I wouldnt have the slightest on how to properly do that. 
Nothing really special about this setup, its all new, fresh directory, fresh DNS, one client added. If I can provide something more specific let me know I can try to accommodate.

Comment: @Seth Anything in the error logs on the DC?  Precise error from the client? Health of the domain?  Output of `dcdiag.exe`?

Comment: ..been looking through it now...here is a 1014 Warning:
"Name resolution for the name _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.VUFOODSLLC.local. timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded."
The SRV record for this error is showing it's there FYI...
DCdiag gives me no errors...

Comment: @seth `Name resolution [...] timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded` would tell you that your problem is that the client is not not able to communicate with the DNS server/Domain Controller for the domain you're trying to join.

Comment: I have these folders in the zones when expanded that say Default-First-Site-Name....Is this normal I don't remember this in other server versions...

Comment: @Seth  Well, screenshots would be helpful... but if the client isn't communicating with the DNS server, that's not going to be the cause of your problem here...

Comment: Ok, I don't know what problem there would be with the client. It's telling me there is a problem with the servers SRV records as I indicated... Isn't that what we're trying to determine? This client had Vista, with same error, reinstalled Win7, get same error. I think we can eliminate the client being the cause of the failure to join the domain...

Comment: @seth  No, the error indicates that the communication to the DNS server is timing out.  This is happening while it's looking for the LDAP SRV record, but the problem is with the communication timing out, not with the SRV record. (According to that error.)  I really don't know what else to say, except that we're now getting the `Please avoid extended discussions in comments` message, but the problem is that the communication between this client and your DNS server is not happening, so that's what you need to fix.

Comment: "Where do I start and how do I fix this in DNS" Was my original question. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this as an issue with the domain server having two adapters and serving two disjointed networks, such as having both a public IP and private IP. I would first check the sites-manager, 'Sites and Services', and see how replication itself is holding up as the SRV record will automatically be removed in such situations.

Comment: run dcdiag and go over the output

Comment: I checked Sites, no replication. Secondary adapter has been disabled. Everything passes dcdiag as stated.
Should I just rebuild the DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the connectcomputer process to join the domain?  Essentials will autojoin without needing to do a manual join.

Comment: Please elaborate on this, as it stands, this answer doesn't appear to be very helpful.

Comment: The connect program gives the same results. It does not perform any function you cannot perform manually. I have tried it for the record.

Answer (score 0):

I'm incredibly embarrassed to admit this but you guys have been helpful. I was adding the server host name to the domain during registration. Im terribly sorry, indeed, bad question.